# Logic for Group by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, for-loop, group-by, count, logic

Input

```
[{"DefectsCount":1,"Release":"5.7.1.0","SWID":"23","AgeBin":"0-20","BinStart":0,"ReleaseSWID":"5.6.1.1.23"},{"DefectsCount":1,"Release":"5.7.1.0","SWID":"172","AgeBin":"0-20","BinStart":0,"ReleaseSWID":"5.7.1.0.172"},{"DefectsCount":1,"Release":"5.6.1.2","SWID":null,"AgeBin":"0-21","BinStart":0}]
```

output

```
[
{"DefectsCount":1,"AgeBin":"0-21","Release":"5.6.1.2"},

{"DefectsCount":2,"AgeBin":"0-20","Release":"5.7.1.0"},

]
```

Need to group by AgeBin and Release and get the count of it

Loadash is not allowed in the project please say how to do it in for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to approach this is to make a key out of the `AgeBin` and `Release` values and sum the `DefectsCount` by that key using `reduce`. This object can then be split out into a result array using `map`:

```js
const data = [{
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.7.1.0",
    SWID: "23",
    AgeBin: "0-20",
    BinStart: 0,
    ReleaseSWID: "5.6.1.1.23",
  },
  {
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.7.1.0",
    SWID: "172",
    AgeBin: "0-20",
    BinStart: 0,
    ReleaseSWID: "5.7.1.0.172",
  },
  {
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.6.1.2",
    SWID: null,
    AgeBin: "0-21",
    BinStart: 0,
  },
]

const out = Object.entries(data.reduce((c, o) => {
    const group = o.AgeBin + '#' + o.Release;
    c[group] = (c[group] || 0) + o.DefectsCount;
    return c;
  }, {}))
  .map(a => {
    [AgeBin, Release] = a[0].split('#');
    DefectsCount = a[1];
    return {
      AgeBin,
      Release,
      DefectsCount
    }
  });

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` with `findIndex` to accumulate the final result. Each iteration, you check if the accumulated result has already had the element with `AgeBin` and `Release`, then either add or modify that element

```
data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const groupIndex = acc.findIndex(
    (g) => g.AgeBin === el.AgeBin && g.Release === el.Release
  )
  if (groupIndex >= 0) {
    acc[groupIndex] = {
      ...acc[groupIndex],
      DefectsCount: acc[groupIndex].DefectsCount + el.DefectsCount,
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({
      DefectsCount: el.DefectsCount,
      AgeBin: el.AgeBin,
      Release: el.Release,
    })
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```

**Runnable example**

```js
const data = [
  {
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.7.1.0",
    SWID: "23",
    AgeBin: "0-20",
    BinStart: 0,
    ReleaseSWID: "5.6.1.1.23",
  },
  {
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.7.1.0",
    SWID: "172",
    AgeBin: "0-20",
    BinStart: 0,
    ReleaseSWID: "5.7.1.0.172",
  },
  {
    DefectsCount: 1,
    Release: "5.6.1.2",
    SWID: null,
    AgeBin: "0-21",
    BinStart: 0,
  },
]

const res = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const groupIndex = acc.findIndex(
    (g) => g.AgeBin === el.AgeBin && g.Release === el.Release
  )
  if (groupIndex >= 0) {
    acc[groupIndex] = {
      ...acc[groupIndex],
      DefectsCount: acc[groupIndex].DefectsCount + el.DefectsCount,
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({
      DefectsCount: el.DefectsCount,
      AgeBin: el.AgeBin,
      Release: el.Release,
    })
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```